# How get a certain values from a list analyzing the value before in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I have a list with integer numbers and I want to extract certain elements with base, in the number before and to increase position to the next number. I would like to do this in loop.

But the numbers in the list will change all the time.

this is my list

```
data = [3, 119, 119, 119, 10, 103, 111, 111, 103, 108, 101, 97, 112, 
105, 115, 3, 99, 111, 109, 0]
```

So, I have the first number 3, then I want to extract the next three numbers, 119 119 119, after these three numbers I have number 10, based in the number 10, I want to extract the next ten positions on the list, 103, 111, 111, 103, 108, 101, 97, 112, 105, 115, afeter that I have number 3, and based on that number extract the next three positions 99, 111, 109, when I find the last number 0 the program stops.

this is my attempts

```
while True:

index1 = 0
index2 = 1

value = data[index1:index2]



index1 = value[0]
index2 = value[0] + 1

print(value)
if value == 0:
    break
```

Comment: So... Do you want to print the groups out or something? Also, please show your attempts.

Comment: sorry, i already edit the post with the code

Comment: Your indentation is wrong - do you get IndentationErrors or is it a copy&paste problem? if copy&paste -please fix.

Comment: @PatrickArtner doesn't matter can be to another  list or a output

Comment: @PatrickArtner is not about identation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try using `itertools.islice`:

```
from itertools import islice

data = [3, 119, 119, 119, 10, 103, 111, 111, 103, 108, 101, 97, 112, 105, 115, 3, 99, 111, 109, 0]

data_iter = iter(data)
for i in data_iter:
    if i == 0:
        break
    print(list(islice(data_iter, i)))
```

Output:

```
[119, 119, 119]
[103, 111, 111, 103, 108, 101, 97, 112, 105, 115]
[99, 111, 109]
```

If you want it as a list, just make the below modifications:

```
from itertools import islice

data = [3, 119, 119, 119, 10, 103, 111, 111, 103, 108, 101, 97, 112, 105, 115, 3, 99, 111, 109, 0]

result = []

data_iter = iter(data)
for i in data_iter:
    if i == 0:
        break
    result.append(list(islice(data_iter, i)))
```

You can even make it a list comprehension if you want:

```
data_iter = iter(data)
result = [list(islice(data_iter, i)) for i in data_iter if i != 0]
```

Answer (score 2):

You can walk over your `data`

- get first element
- get a list sliced based on current items index and its value
- skip all those elements you just sliced out
  repeat until done:

---

```
data = [3, 119, 119, 119, 10, 103, 111, 111, 103, 108, 101, 97, 112, 105, 115, 
        3, 99, 111, 109, 0]

part = []
skip = 0
for idx,val in enumerate(data):
    if skip == 0:
        part.append(data[idx+1:idx+1+val])
        skip = val
    else:
        skip -= 1

if not part[-1]:
    part.pop()

print(part)
```

Output:

```
[[119, 119, 119], 
 [103, 111, 111, 103, 108, 101, 97, 112, 105, 115], 
 [99, 111, 109]]
```

Doku:

- [enumerate(iterable)](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate) returns (index,value) tuples from the iterable

Comment: This works... i already accept the answer before, but thank you for your time :)

Comment: @Gab It is fine :) it is good to have different solutions to a problem